# R bubble plot using ggplot manually selecting the colour and axis names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I using ggplot to create a bubble plot.  With this code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = mean, size = n, fill = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme() + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 50)) + 
  ylim(0,100)
```

It is working perfectly apart from 2 things:

1. For each name (fill) I would like to manually specify the colour used (via a dataframe that maps name to colour) - this is to provide consistency across multiple figures.
2. I would like to substitute the numbers on the y for text labels (for several reasons I cannot use the text labels from the outset due to ordering issues)

I have tried several methods using scale_color_manual() and scale_y_continuous respectively and I am getting nowhere!  Any help would be very gratefully received!

Thanks

Comment: welcome welcome. [have a look how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, for all your help, this worked perfectly:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = mean, size = n, fill = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = gcolors) +
  scale_size(limits = c(min(df$n), max(df$n))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = order, labels = order_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified an example `df`, I created one of my own.

To manually specify the color, you have to use `scale_fill_manual` with a named vector as the argument of `values`.

**Edit 2**

This appears to do what you want. We use `scale_y_continuous`. The `breaks` argument specifies the vector of positions, while the `labels` argument specifies the labels which should appear at those positions. Since we already created the vectors when creating the data frame, we simply pass those vectors as arguments.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = mean, size = n, fill = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = gcolors) +
  scale_size(limits = c(min(df$n), max(df$n))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = mean, labels = order_label)
```

**Edit 1**

From your comment, it appears that you want to label the circles. One option would be to use `geom_text`. Code below. You may need to experiment with values of `nudge_y` to get the position correct.

```
order <- c(1, 2)
mean <- c(0.75, 0.3)
n <- c(180, 200)
name <- c("a", "b")
order_label <- c("New York", "London")
df <- data.frame(order, mean, n, name, order_label, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

color <- c("blue", "red")
name_color <- data.frame(name, color, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gcolors <- name_color[, 2]
names(gcolors) <- name_color[, 1]

ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = mean, size = n, fill = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(label = order_label), size = 3, hjust = "inward",
            nudge_y = 0.03) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = gcolors) +
  scale_size(limits = c(min(df$n), max(df$n))) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  ylab(NULL)
```

**Original Answer**

It is not clear what you mean by "substitute the numbers on the y for text labels". In the example below, I have formatted the y-axis as a percentage using the `scales::percent_format()` function. Is this similar to what you want?

```
order <- c(1, 2)
mean <- c(0.75, 0.3)
n <- c(180, 200)
name <- c("a", "b")
df <- data.frame(order, mean, n, name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

color <- c("blue", "red")
name_color <- data.frame(name, color, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gcolors <- name_color[, 2]
names(gcolors) <- name_color[, 1]

ggplot(df, aes(x = order, y = mean, size = n, fill = name)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = gcolors) +
  scale_size(limits = c(min(df$n), max(df$n))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Comment: thank you the coloring works perfectly.  Apologies for the poor explanation.  Using your example i wish to relabel 1 on the y axis to london and 2 on the y to NYC

Comment: @Rob I have edited my answer to provide another option. Does this work for you?

Comment: sorry I have not explained it well, your amendment labels the bubbles but i was hoping to replace the numerical value on the Y axis itself with a character label

Comment: @Rob I have made another edit - this should give what you want. If this works, kindly accept the answer.